# Why is LWJGL display window a long

Tags: java, lwjgl

in the example, I see this line being used: `private long window;`

why is window a `long` object? what kind of metadata is stored there?

I know this works, but just wondering why is it a long object instead of a usual Display class similar object in other game libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I think I found the reason: `long` is used to indicate the **address** to the display window, not really the window itself. So really the window should be called `windowAddress`